# Android, gradle cannot sync: Failed to resolve: firebase-messaging-license?

Tags: android, firebase

This happened suddenly today. I just have worked on the project for so long and never have had such problem. Here is a log:

```
D:\AndroidStudio\AndroidStudioProjects\myapp\app\build.gradle
Error:Failed to resolve: firebase-messaging
Error:Failed to resolve: firebase-core
Error:Failed to resolve: firebase-analytics-impl
Error:Failed to resolve: firebase-iid
Error:Failed to resolve: firebase-common
Error:Failed to resolve: play-services-gcm
Error:Failed to resolve: play-services-location
Error:Failed to resolve: play-services-base
Error:Failed to resolve: play-services-iid
Error:Failed to resolve: play-services-tasks
Error:Failed to resolve: play-services-basement
Error:Failed to resolve: play-services-gcm-license
Error:Failed to resolve: firebase-analytics-license
Error:Failed to resolve: play-services-tasks-license
Error:Failed to resolve: play-services-iid-license
```

I took a screenshot of the full log:
[image: Errors happen when syncing gradle]

I have done anything I knew. I cleaned the project, rebuilt it, invalidated and restarted my Android Studio, and even more. But none helped. How can I bring the project back to work?

Side note: I even restored previous backups of the project but they also didn't sync.

Side note: Other projects are syncing and working well with the same Android Studio.

This is also the project gradle:

```
plugins {
id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.8.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {

    manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "----",
                            onesignal_google_project_number: "---"]

    applicationId "com.myapp.android"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
compile 'com.gelitenight.waveview:waveview:1.0.0'
compile 'me.itangqi.waveloadingview:library:0.3.5'
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.7'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.snatik:storage:2.1.0'

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'

compile project(':universalvideoview')
compile 'com.github.faruktoptas:FancyShowCaseView:1.0.0'

compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.7.1'

compile 'com.danikula:videocache:2.7.0'

compile 'com.github.obolsh:rambooster:1.0.2@aar' //STest

compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.0.1'

compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: check your sdk please, make sure you have installed Google play service and stuffs. Even if installed and not updated, update that first

Comment: Can you check your global gradle setting? make sure your **Offline work** in not selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I just noticed it was an issue from `OneSingnal` library:

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.7.1'
```

I used a range of versions so `gradle` be able to decide what is the best version. Something like this:

```
compile'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.5.3,4.0.0)'
```

Surprisingly this worked and the errors disappeared. I still don't know why the issue happened all of a sudden though and what was the logic behind it.